# MySQL: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=2

Tags: php, mysql, max-allowed-packet

I try to execute a very simple query to delete one row. the "max_allowed_packet" equals "1073741824" that's why I'm confused why I get

```
Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=2
```

I select just 25 rows from a table to send their data via sms and sleep(1) after deleting the row.

Query:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("select * from sms limit 25");
$stmt->execute();
```

I loop through rows here and send row data via sms then delete it

```
$q = $db->prepare("delete from sms where id = '$r[id]'");
$q->execute();
sleep(1)
```

But sometimes (just sometimes not every time) I get that error and row doesn't get deleted so the sms message is sent so many times to the same user because it's still in the table. Any ideas to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Side note not related to the problem but usefull information: SQL is a unsordered set of data.. SQL also doesnt guarantee running the query `select * from TABLE limit 25` would give the same results without using ORDER BY..

Comment: What are you trying the do precisely.. Because you "obfuscated"the tables names it's hard to see if you use one table or two tabels.  Provide table structure(s), some example records place it on sql-fiddle.com or db-fiddle.com also we need the expected results as a ascii (text formatted) table also more PHP code would be nice.

Comment: The same table select then delete

Comment: Why not simply use `DELETE FROM sms ORDER BY id LIMIT 25` ?

Comment: Because I delete the row if the sms gateway responds with success otherwise I don't delete the row @Raymond Nijland

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a pattern like

```
prepare mysql query a
execute mysql query a
for each row in result set a
    prepare mysql query b
    execute mysql quer b
```

you must use a separate db connection for mysql query b. Why? query a can still be using its connection as long as you're reading rows from its result set.

Comment: So you mean
open connection
prepare
execute
save id value in a parameter
close connection
open the same connection again
prepare
execute
close connection again ??

Comment: open connection
prepare and execute
if message sent open a new connection
prepare
execute
close inner connection
continue loop